# Symfony UX Autocomplete how to modify end point url with custom js controller (client side)

Tags: symfony

I need a autocomplete field depending of the value of an other select form element.

In other words I would like to take control of the url value from a js controller.

I guess it might be possible by creating a custom Stimulus controller and listen to one or both events that the core Stimulus controller dispatches like :[Extending Tom Select](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-autocomplete/current/index.html#extending-tom-select)

I didn't find example to do that.

Thanks for your help